# How to configure multiple addresses on a single interface using Fedora 16

Tags: linux, networking, ip, fedora

I upgraded from Fedora 14 to 16, recently. I had two static IP v4 addresses configured on my ethernet interface by creating two files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:

```
  ifcfg-eth0      -> first address
  ifcfg-eth0:1    -> second address
```

After the upgrade, this resulted in an error message during the boot process and in only the *second* address being successfully configured on the interface. So, what is the correct way to configure multiple addresses on a single interface on Fedora 16? I could not find anything on this subject in the documentation so far.

Comment: Can you post the error you are talking about?

Comment: you can create multiple addr for an interface by creating network alias only

Answer (score 3):

The command to configure virtual addresses on your interface in fc16 is:

# ip addr add 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0

Replace the IP address and device name with apropriate values for your system. Be sure to use CIDR notation, or the system will default to /32

To see the result of the command use:

# ip addr list

To remove an address:

# ip addr del 192.168.1.10/24 dev eth0

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will addresses added with "ip addr add" still be available after reboot? Do you know where the information is persisted? I currently don't have the opportunity to try it out...

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: I'm still not sure what actually caused this problem though I suspect the NetworkManager was somehow to blame. I finally used `system-config-network-gui` to review, update and save the configuration, unchecking the option "Controlled by NetworkManager". This seems to have solved the issue for me. Thanks for your time!